# Elastic Search filter by count of a nested document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic search index for **firms**, that has a nested object called **transactions**. The transactions have at least a **date** field. Here is a sample:

```
firms: [
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "address" : "xyz",
    "transactions": [
       {
         "date" : "2014-12-20"
         "side" : "buyer"
       },
       ...
     ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Given this data, I want to query for all firms having (say) 3+ transactions in the past 6 or 12 months.

The following query returns firms having at least one transaction in the past 12 months:

```
POST firms/firm/_search
    {
    "query": {
        "nested": {
           "path": "transactions",
           "query": {
               "bool": {
                   "must": [
                      {
                          "match": {
                             "transactions.side": "buyer"
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          "range": {
                             "transactions.date": {
                                "from": "2014-10-24",
                                "to": "2015-10-24"
                             }
                          }
                      }
                   ]
               }
           }
        }  
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how would I extend this query to match firms having x+ transactions in a period of y+ months. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have other option than using a `script`. Something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "transactions",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "transactions.side": "buyer"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "transactions.date": {
                        "from": "2014-10-24",
                        "to": "2015-10-24"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "filtered": {
            "filter": {
              "script": {
                "script": "if(_source.transactions.size<3) return false;fromDate=Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd',fromDateParam);toDate=Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd',toDateParam);count=0;for(d in _source.transactions){docsDate=Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd',d.get('date'));if(docsDate>=fromDate && docsDate<=toDate){count++};if(count==3){return true;}};return false;",
                "params": {
                  "fromDateParam":"2014-10-24",
                  "toDateParam":"2015-10-24"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The actual `range` filter is an "optimization" for those documents where none of the dates matches. So that, this document (with no dates in the range) will not reach the more costly `script` filter.

The `script` itself first checks if the number of transactions is less than `3`. If it is, don't bother doing all the date checks and return `false`. If it's more than `3` then take each date and compare with the parameters. As soon as a count of `3` is reached stop looking at the rest of the dates and return `true`.

Comment: Thanks Val for your solution. I tried your query in sense, but I get various errors related to the functions: size, parse and so on (PropertyAccessException[[Error: unable to resolve method: java.util.Date.parse(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)). Do you have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you enable scripting in ES?