# How do you find documents where inner_hits count is N?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

How can I find documents where `inner_hits` count is exactly N?

I have a customer. My customer has a nested collection of invoices.

I want to find all customers that have exactly 2 unpaid invoices and I have trouble doing that. I think I can find those that have at least 2, using `min_doc_count`, but how to make it an exact value?

Comment: How do you update the nested array in your documents? Ideally you should add one or more fields at the root level that contain exactly this information, i.e. `"paidCount": 10, "unpaidCount": 2`. Then finding those documents is simply a matter of matching those fields.

Comment: What if I want to find 2 unpaid invoices that also had to happen in a specific date time range? Basically what I'm saying is that I need a query as the criteria for sub-documents are dynamic. 

I tried to simplify my requirements but I might have overdone it :)

Comment: Ok, I understand, if you need other criteria, then of course you'll need to query your data dynamically. It would help, though, if you could show a sample document.

Comment: ping, can you show a sample document ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it by **script**.

```
{
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "script": {
                "script": "if(_source.invoices.size<3) return false;{other conditions come here.}",
                "params": {
                    "param1": null,
                    "param2": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can find a very similar solution here:
[Elastic Search filter by count of a nested document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316956/elastic-search-filter-by-count-of-a-nested-document)

Comment: One does not have access to nested collection in scripts. It's null there.

Comment: Did you use **nested** in query?